# Why is my Azure App Configuration instance is being throttled?

Tags: azure-app-configuration

I have a basic instance of Azure App Configuration. It's supposed to allow 1000 requests per day.

The usage chart for the previous day looks like this:

[image]

But I can no longer open Configuration Explorer or Feature Manager. Getting these errors:

[image]

I don't understand why requests started to being throttled since the usage is nowhere near 1000 per day.

Answer (score 0):

Throttling is based on the 24-hour day of the UTC time (not the local time). Please make sure the whole day is counted.